# Visual Studio 2017 Offline Installation Still Wants Internet Connection

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017, offline

I created an offline layout folder using the following command:

```
vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --add Component.GitHub.VisualStudio --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

I then copied the entire resulted vs2017layout folder (~2.57GB) to another machine that does not have internet access and ran the following command:

```
vs_enterprise.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --add Component.GitHub.VisualStudio --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

However, the installer still wants internet connection. Please advise on what I'm missing.
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi AngieM, please use this command: vs_enterprise.exe
 --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --add Component.GitHub.VisualStudio –includeOptional to have a try. Before the installation, open the Certificates folder in your offline cache and install the certificates as admin. Check this similar issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/39981/can-not-install-offline-unable-to-download-install-1.html, add the --noweb option to test.

Comment: Before installing from your current layout, was there a VS already installed? If having VS already installed though from offline layout but not same path as your current layout, update will not use your current layout. You need to uninstall your VS and reinstall from your current layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I need to manually import the certificates that were downloaded to the offline folder on the machine.

Found this info from this blog post: http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2016/11/visual-studio-2017-offline-installer.html#C3t0q0XUUVqgvqyy.97

Comment: So glad to hear that your issue is solved, you can mark it as answer and that will help other community members to easier search this useful information.

Comment: see this link too (how to Install certificates required for Visual Studio offline installation):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-certificates-for-visual-studio-offline

Answer (score 2):

Please run https://aka.ms/vscollect.exe and upload your logs to a new issue on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com. Logs will then only be available for you and us to see and diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this kind of problem. However I managed to solve it by installing Visual Studio in online computer from downloaded Layout, waiting for installation to complete, then copy the Download Cache (by default located in `%programdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages`) into existing Layout.

This way some missing packages also get included and hopefully the layout installer no longer require internet for next offline installations.

Answer (score 0):

When started, installer download file Catalog.json, containing list of all packages, versions, file sizes and checksum. Using this data installer check size and crc of all already downloaded files, using information in file Catalog.json at installation root. 
If Your installer not use downloaded files, this may be due to the following reasons:

1. incomplete download, wrong size or crc of downloaded files (View
   file Catalog.json at installation root.);
2. there is newer version of file (version,crc & size look at Catalog.json).